# Why was the miracle of Purim conducted מדה כנגד מדה?

Tags: purim

Why was the miracle of Purim and the punishments exacted against Haman necessary to be   מדה כנגד מדה?

Seemingly Haman could have had his head chopped off or another method of killing, why specifically is so much of the Purim story "measure for measure"?

Comment: That's how Hashem does justice. Same goes for Exodus and many other examples.

Comment: @shmosel Can you please share any sources for this?

Comment: Do you mean mida kneged mida in general or why did it have to be specifically on the gallows that he prepared?

Comment: @Chatzkel there is a lot of Midah K'neged Midah in the story. it is similar to the "v'nehapoch".

Comment: Like @shmosel said that is how hashem does everything, see sotah 8b sanhedrin 90ab